# is there a way to Change the Current url from Map Route to another Map Route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, maproute

i have two Map Route :

1- "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

2-"{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"

all i want is there is a way to Convert link : DomainName.com/Login/Register (Map Route 1)
to
DomainName.com/en/Login/Register (Map Route 2)

without Lose Action,Controller or id

Comment: You mean that the url would be rewrote to `DomainName.com/en/Login/Register` when you enter url `DomainName.com/Login/Register`?And the action is the original `Login/Register`?

Answer (score 0):

i did it by JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = window.location.href;
var segments = url.split('/');
console.log(url);
console.log(segments);
if (segments.includes("en")) {
    segments.splice(3, 1, "ar");
    var newAr = segments.join("/");
    console.log(newAr);
    $(".changeAr").click(function () {
        window.location.replace(newAr);

    });
} else if (segments.includes("ar")) {
    segments.splice(3, 1, "en");
    var newEn = segments.join("/");
    console.log(newEn);
    $(".changeEn").click(function () {
        window.location.replace(newEn);
        console.log(newEn);
    });
} else {
    segments.splice(3, 0, "en");
    var newEn = segments.join("/");
    console.log(newEn);
    $(".changeEn").click(function () {
        window.location.replace(newEn);
    });
    segments.splice(3, 1, "ar");
    var newAr = segments.join("/");
    console.log(newAr);
    $(".changeAr").click(function () {
        window.location.replace(newAr);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the URL string by'/' character and enter culture at index[1]:

```
string UrlWithCulture(string url, string culture)
{
  string[] split = url.Split("/");
  return $"{split[0]}/{culture}/{string.Join("/",split.Skip(1))}";
}
```

Comment: but how i send url from view to controller ??

Comment: In RouteConfig set culture to UrlParameter.Optional

Comment: "{culture?}/{controller=}/{action=}/{id?}" like this ?? 
ok but how i send the url from view to controller ????